# How to make multi-selection drop down and search a subform in MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

So i have a Multi-Selection Dropdown. I would like to filter my search criteria in a the subform. On my parent form i have a combobox called [cboTicketStatus]. my subform is [SubHelpdeskTickets] and the source object is [sfrm_Helpdesk_Ticket_Filter_Search]. 
In my combobox called [cboTicketStatus], i have several items to select: Open, Closed, Work In Progress, Hold, Approval Needed, Approved. I would like to be able to select multiple items and then the subform filter by the items selected in the [cboTicketStatus]. Then if no itmes selected i would like it to show all items from the Table [tbl_Helpdesk_Ticket_Tracker]. Im not sure how to write the code to change the Record Source to do this.

```
Function SearchCriteria()
Dim strDepartment As String
Dim strTicketNumber As String
Dim strTicketStatus As String
Dim strStartDate As String
Dim strEndDate As String
Dim task As String
Dim strCriteria As String

If IsNull(Me.cboDepartments) Then
    strDepartment = "[Comptroller Department] like '*'"
Else
    strDepartment = "[Comptroller Department] = '" & Me.cboDepartments.Column(1) & "'"
End If
If IsNull(Me.cboTicketNumber) Then
    strTicketNumber = "[Helpdesk Ticket Number] like '*'"
Else
    strTicketNumber = "[Helpdesk Ticket Number] = '" & Me.cboTicketNumber.Column(1) & "'"
End If
If IsNull(Me.cboTicketStatus) Then
    strTicketStatus = "[Status of Ticket] like '*'"
Else
    strTicketStatus = "[Status of Ticket] = '" & Me.cboTicketStatus.Column(1) & "'"
End If
If IsNull(Me.txtStartDate) Then
    strStartDate = "[Date Opened] like '*'"
Else
    strStartDate = "([Date Opened] >= #" & Me.txtStartDate & "#)"
End If
If IsNull(Me.txtEndDate) Then
    strEndDate = "[Date Opened] like '*'"
Else
    strEndDate = "([Date Opened] <= #" & Me.txtEndDate & "#)"
End If
strCriteria = strDepartment & "And" & strTicketNumber & "And" & strStartDate & "And" & strEndDate & "And" & strTicketStatus
    task = "Select * from tbl_Helpdesk_Ticket_Tracker where " & strCriteria
    Me.SubHelpdeskTickets.Form.RecordSource = task
    Me.SubHelpdeskTickets.Form.Requery
End Function
```

My code i am using right now only works with a single selection.

updated the code for what you edited. 
Im getting another error.
Am i putting it together correctly?

````
    strTicketStatus = "[TicketStatus] like '*'"
Else
    strTicketStatus = "[TicketStatus] = "
    Dim i As Long
    'Dim selectedStatus As String
    Dim firstCondition As Boolean: firstCondition = True
    For i = 0 To Me.cboTicketStatus.ListCount - 1
        If Me.cboTicketStatus.Selected(i) = True Then
             selectedStatus = Me.cboTicketStatus.ItemData(i)
             strTicketStatus = strTicketStatus & IIf(Not firstCondition, " OR ", "") & _
                "'" & selectedStatus & "'"
        firstCondition = False
    End If
Next i
End If```

[![First View of All tickets][1]][1]


[![after selecting an option in the dropdown][2]][2]


[![view after event is fired][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vXqT.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i079f.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egUj8.jpg
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
strTicketStatus = "[Status of Ticket] IN ("
Dim i as Long
Dim firstCondition as boolean: firstCondition = true
For i = 0 to Me.cboTicketStatus.ListCount - 1
    if Me.cboTicketStatus.Selected(i) = True then
        selectedStatus = Me.cboTicketStatus.ItemData(i) 
        strTicketStatus = strTicketStatus  & iif(not firstCondition, ", ", "") & "'" & selectdStatus & "'"
        firstCondition = false
    End If
Next i
strTicketStatus = strTicketStatus & ")"
```

Comment: So when i place that in my code i get an error variable "i" not defined? any ideas on this. My coding is limited any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: If I do it this way: Dim i As String ; I get Type Mismatch error.

Comment: So i changed Dim i As String to Dim i As Long and now i do not get any errors. However, When i test the selection drop down and select multiple items when the subform requeries it is blank. So i just tried selecting one item from the dropdown and when the subform requeries it is blank. I remove the selections and i see everything from my query in my subform.

Comment: Another error that comes up with making a selection is: Run-time error '3075'

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[DepartmentForm] like '*'And[ticketNumber] like '*'And[DateEntered] like'*'And[DateEntered] like'*'And[TicketeStatus]=OR'?".

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in the code. I have edited it. Good luck.

Comment: review my update. to my post. i feel i may be putting this together wrong. Any advice?

Comment: i added some pics for you to see what it is doing.

Comment: I have edited my code. It was thought to be an example of the kind of things to do. In fact the syntax of the generated condition was wrong. Now I think it's better. Anyway you could delete all the  `strXXX= "[XXX] like '*'"` and replace them with an empty string, that would make your query rather faster, I'd guess. To do that, you'll have to change the condition at the end, of course, but I guess that's not such a big difficulty.

Comment: So is it ok to have it wrapped in `If ISNull` statement? should i replace: `If IsNull(Me.cboTicketStatus) Then
    strTicketStatus = "[Status of Ticket] like '*'"
Else` with your code and leave it at that. I am able to make mulitiple selections now. however, my subform returns blank? any thoughts. Could my issue be that the value in the subform field is string in a text box and the selections are coming from a combo box with its record source a query allowing multiple selections?

Comment: I do want to thank you for all your help. it is greatly appreciated

Comment: You should debug the code, see what value the "task" variable has it in the end. Build a query with that text (New Query->Sql->Paste) and see if it selects what you want.